# How can I limit number of posts per day?

Tags: nodes

I need to limit number of forum posts that a user can create per day to, for example, 5 posts. How exactly can I do so using rules?

I know that there is a [Node Limit Number](http://drupal.org/project/node_limitnumber) module for this, but it ultimately needs to create rules, and I've got stock there.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you install that module and have trouble? If so, what happened?

Comment: By forum posts do you mean comments on a forum node or the forum node itself?

Comment: @beth The OP explained which is _the problem_ with the module.

Comment: I was not sure whether they were trying to use rules with the module, or instead of it.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a solution for your problem with Node Limit Number, maybe one of these modules are easier for you to implement?

- [Node Limit](http://drupal.org/project/node_limit) (D6, D7 alpha)
- [User Quota](http://drupal.org/project/user_quota) (D6)

There is also a comparison of similar modules [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/16637).